# MATLAB Generated C Code Compilation Error

Tags: c, matlab

I have a MATLAB function that has signal processing and machine learning and I wanted to test it on another OS like linux. So I use codegen to generate C code for that function. When I come to run it (predictActivityFromSignalBuffer) on the command line, this is what I get:

```
MacBook-Pro-2:predictActivityFromSignalBuffer kareem$ gcc predictActivityFromSignalBuffer.c
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "_featuresFromBuffer", referenced from:
       _predictActivityFromSignalBuffer in predictActivityFromSignalBuffer-1a1886.o
    "_main", referenced from:
      implicit entry/start for main executable
    "_mynn", referenced from:
      _predictActivityFromSignalBuffer in predictActivityFromSignalBuffer-1a1886.o
    "_rtIsNaN", referenced from:
      _predictActivityFromSignalBuffer in predictActivityFromSignalBuffer-1a1886.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What is this error telling me exactly? I have no idea how to debug this or where to start/look.

Comment: `predictActivityFromSignalBuffer.c` has dependencies on other items.  The linker can't find those specific items.  Try to get the smallest possible example working first.  Did you call these functions ("`mynn`, e.g.) without defining them?  Do you have an entry point defined (a `main()` function)?

Comment: you are getting linker error, it occurs during linking time. when you don't declare function and just try to use them. Show us your code so that we can be more useful. you might need to define a `filename.h` file. Which will contain the declaration of these function except `main()`.

Comment: codegen isn't designed to produce a standalone executable.  If you are trying to "deploy" a MATLAB function onto a different system that doesn't have MATLAB installed, the MATLAB compiler is what you need.

Comment: A makefile is generated along with C and header files when you generate C code from MATLAB. Try using that to compile your code. That will correctly include all dependencies. If you are moving generated code to different machine make sure you copy all the generated files.

Answer (score 2):

Did you really just call

```
$ gcc predictActivityFromSignalBuffer.c
```

without any other dependencies? Usually there come a lot of other files with a code generation that have to be linked.

I do not know what you have done to produce your .c file. I recommend to use the coder wizard by typing

```
coder
```

in the Matlab command window. This will guide you through the whole process of code generation and also offers a lot of support and testing possibilities. You can also choose to compile your functions to ready-to-use DLL libraries or executatables. Just have a look at it.